# Initialize C++/CLI array of structures

Tags: c++-cli

I wish to partially initialize an array of structures like in a C++ POD type.  The String^ would normally be a char* but managed C++ doesn't allow that.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

ref struct Field
{
    String^ name;
    int fences;
    int length;
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    array<Field^>^ farm =
    {
        { "eenie", 10 },
        { "meenie", 20 },
        { "miny", 4 }
    };

    for each (Field^ field in farm)
    {
        field->length = field->fences * 22;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This results in

```
1>arrayinit.cpp(18): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [6]' to 'Field ^'
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'Field ^'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          Cannot convert an unmanaged type to a managed type
```

So I tried

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

ref struct Field
{
    String^ name;
    int fences;
    int length;
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    array<Field^>^ farm =
    {
        { String("eenie"), 10 },
        { String("meenie"), 20 },
        { String("miny"), 4 }
    };

    for each (Field^ field in farm)
    {
        field->length = field->fences * 22;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now I get

```
1>arrayinit.cpp(18): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'System::String' to 'Field ^'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>arrayinit.cpp(18): error C2078: too many initializers
```

Almost every example I've looked at only tells how to initialize an array of strings or integers.  I haven't found out a way of initializing an array of structures containing strings.

Is there a simple way of doing this or do I have to create a special constructor and gcnew every element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can gcnew every element with a special constructor.  Is there a simpler way of doing this similar to a POD initialization?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

ref struct Field
{
    String^ name;
    int fences;
    int length;

    Field(String^ x, int in_fences)
    {
        name = x;
        fences = in_fences;
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    array<Field^>^ farm =
    {
        gcnew Field("eenie", 10 ),
        gcnew Field("meenie", 20 ),
        gcnew Field("miny", 4 )
    };

    for each (Field^ field in farm)
    {
        field->length = field->fences * 22;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, if Field is changed to a value instead of a reference,

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

value struct Field
{
    String^ name;
    int fences;
    int length;

    Field(String^ x, int in_fences)
    {
        name = x;
        fences = in_fences;
    }

    void Init()
    {
        length = fences * 22;
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    array<Field>^ farm =
    {
        Field("eenie", 10 ),
        Field("meenie", 20 ),
        Field("miny", 4 )
    };

    for each (Field% field in farm)
    {
        field.Init();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is slightly better than gcnewing every field.

Comment: Make sure you understand what it means to use a `value struct` and how that changes behavior. One thing I've always seen with C++/CLI is that it is rarely, if ever, elegant. It is designed to work, but that is about it (everything C# does easily and succinctly is typically absent).

Comment: Yes - I understand the differences and pitfalls between ref and value.    I've been forced into using C++/CLI because of WinForms.  Could do a mix of C++ and C++/CLI but it is easier if all the code is in the same language.

Comment: I only use C++/CLI as a bridge between .Net and C++ code (my own or in libraries). I'd rather have three languages than to deal with the clunky C++/CLI syntax for a lot more.